# What is the best automatic background subtraction algorithm for single image?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am new to the field of computer vision. I found few background subtraction algorithms for frames from video but I am unable to find any which works on individual image which is automatic. I am not looking for the interactive ones.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

background subtraction work for sequence images. You may use segmentation or thresholding which can work in individual image.

Comment: I tried using thresholding but it does not work in my case as it is not just the background and objects. The images are of objects placed on a palm and there are chances of some random objects in the background also.